# Horizontal Linear RecyclerView stop scrolling beyond points

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with a linear horizontal RecyclerView.
I'm using it as a bar-graph to show the steps made per day.

The orientation is horizontal and it is a linear layoutmanager.

As it is embedded in a fragment which itself is embedded in a tabbed view it
works great for scrolling and snapping to the center object.

Now I want to add some more element (+5 on each side) to have a nicer look.
Also, this will allow the user to scroll to the last element (as it is tricky with the snappy thing) and fill up empty space.

The emtpy elemnts will be grayed out to signal that those elements are not available.

My problem is now: I want the user to be able to scroll between the first and last available element and stop scrolling when reaching the end so that the last or first element will be in the center.

I don't know how to achieve this.
Can I handle this somehow in OnScroll and ask which element is currently in the center? Maybe I can set a flag in the element itself which says: first and last and check if one of those is in focus?

How could I realize this behaviour?